# Play RTSP video with Qt VLC libary in C++

Tags: c++, qml, vlc-qt

I am trying to connect my `VlcVideoPlayer` from VLCQt libary to any video streamed from url with **rts protocol**.

Currently, this is my code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import VLCQt 1.0
VlcVideoPlayer {
    property var first: true
    id: vidwidget
    anchors.fill: parent
    objectName: "vlcMediaPlayer"
    url: "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov" // "http://samples.mplayerhq.hu/A-codecs/AAC/ct_faac.mp4"
    volume: 100
    aspectRatio: "16:10"
    autoplay: true
}
```

It works with *https://* , but when I try to change it to *rtps://*, my console only prints out

```
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
VLC-Qt "1.1.0" initialised
Using libvlc version: "2.2.2 Weatherwax"
Format: chroma: I420 width: 240 height: 162 pitches: 0 lines: 0
YV12 3 0
libvlc Error: "Track identifier not found"
libvlc: Failed to change zoom
libvlc: Failed to set on top
libvlc: Failed to change source AR
```

and nothing happens - no video shows up.

When I tried to show current time of video with `console.log(time)`, time was changing so I guess it plays video, but it doesn't show up.

Anyone have experience with this? Where am I doing mistake?

Thanks for your help!

//Edit:

I didn't notice first, but I am getting audio, but not video.

Comment: Are you sure this url transmite rts?

Comment: @folibis I am getting audio

Comment: @Brykyz 
I tried to open it with rtsp with vlc and it does not work. with http it works but not with rtsp or rtp.

Comment: @eyllanesc So VLCQt doesn't support rtsp?

Comment: @eyllanesc It's random stream found on internet, it should be streaming BigBuckBunny video, normally it can be opened with any program wich provides video playing

Comment: @eyllanesc Sorry, i don't understand what you mean, "is hidden" and "make it more visible"

Comment: @Brykyz 
if this url is the one that brings you the problem then it should not be commented, that makes it little visible but you should place it directly: `url: "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov"`

Comment: @eyllanesc Oh, ok, sorry, done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I have solved it after some searching on [this page](https://vlc-qt.tano.si/reference/git/hierarchy.html), I have found something like `VlcQmlPlayer`, functions are almost same as in `VlcQmlVideoPlayer`, except it's newer and it's source is subclass of `VlcQmlVideoOutput`. So I registered few types for QML:

```
qmlRegisterUncreatableType<Vlc>("Vlc", 1, 1, "Vlc", QStringLiteral("Vlc cannot be instantiated directly"));
qmlRegisterUncreatableType<VlcQmlSource>("VlcSource", 1, 1, "VlcSource", QStringLiteral("VlcQmlSource cannot be instantiated directly"));
qmlRegisterUncreatableType<VlcTrackModel>("VlcTrackModel", 1, 1, "VlcTrackModel", QStringLiteral("VlcTrackModel cannot be instantiated directly"));
qmlRegisterType<VlcQmlVideoOutput>("VlcVideoOutput", 1, 1, "VlcVideoOutput");
qmlRegisterType<VlcQmlPlayer>("VlcPlayer", 1, 1, "VlcPlayer");
```

and after that, I used it in QML like this

```
import VlcPlayer 1.1
import Vlc 1.1
import VlcVideoOutput 1.1

VlcVideoOutput {
    source:
        VlcPlayer {
        id: vlcPlayer
        url: "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My code is as shown below

Main.cpp

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include <QtQuick/QQuickView>

#include <VLCQtCore/Common.h>
#include <VLCQtQml/QmlSource.h>
#include <VLCQtCore/TrackModel.h>
#include <VLCQtQml/Qml.h>
#include <VLCQtQml/QmlVideoObject.h>
#include <VLCQtCore/MediaPlayer.h>
#include <VLCQtQml/QmlPlayer.h>
#include <VLCQtQml/QmlVideoOutput.h>
#include <QtPlugin>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("VLC-Qt QML Player");
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_X11InitThreads);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    VlcCommon::setPluginPath(app.applicationDirPath() + "/plugins");
    qmlRegisterUncreatableType<Vlc>("Vlc", 1, 1, "Vlc", QStringLiteral("Vlc cannot be instantiated directly"));
    qmlRegisterUncreatableType<VlcQmlSource>("VlcSource", 1, 1, "VlcSource", QStringLiteral("VlcQmlSource cannot be instantiated directly"));
    qmlRegisterUncreatableType<VlcTrackModel>("VlcTrackModel", 1, 1, "VlcTrackModel", QStringLiteral("VlcTrackModel cannot be instantiated directly"));
    qmlRegisterType<VlcQmlVideoOutput>("VlcVideoOutput", 1, 1, "VlcVideoOutput");
    qmlRegisterType<VlcQmlPlayer>("VlcPlayer", 1, 1, "VlcPlayer");
```

Main.qml

```
import VlcPlayer 1.1
import Vlc 1.1
import VlcVideoOutput 1.1

VlcVideoOutput {
    source:
        VlcPlayer {
        id: vlcPlayer
        url: "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference, you can replace all these qmlRegister() functions with:

```
#include <VLCQtCore/Common.h>
#include <VLCQtQml/Qml.h>

int main( )
{
...
    VlcCommon::setPluginPath( app.applicationDirPath( ) + "/plugins" );
    VlcQml::registerTypes( );
...
}
```

And

```
import VLCQt 1.1

VlcVideoOutput {
    source:
        VlcPlayer {
            url: "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov"
    }
}
```